# Указать динамический путь к элементу объекта JS

Tags: javascript, объекты, key

Прошу прощения, если не смог верно указать в названии суть задачи.

Есть многомерный объект в котором может быть разное кол-во уровней.

```
lib = {"lvl1":{"lvl2":{"lvl3":"value"}}}
```

Также есть список ключей, по которым можно найти значение `value`. Их число также может меняться.

```
keys = ["key1","key2","key3"]
```

Вопрос, как найти по списку ключей `keys` значение `value` в объекте `lib`? Нужно получить именно ссылку к объекту, что бы можно было его изменить.
Если была бы фиксированная вложенность, то можно было использовать:

```
lib[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = new_var
```

на данный момент не нашел ничего умнее, как определить кол-во ключей в `keys`, и обычной конструкцией `if else` указывать на подходящий "шаблон"

```
if(keys.length == 1){
    lib[keys[0]] == new_var;
}else if(keys.length == 2){
    lib[keys[0]][keys[1]] == new_var;
}
// ... и т.д.
```

Пытался найти решение через циклы и автоматически добавлять ключи, но реализация получается только через `eval`

Вложенность примерно в интервале 1-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна рекурсия:

```
function getElement(lib, keys) {
    var key = keys.shift();
    return keys.length ? getElement(lib[key], keys) : lib[key];
}

function setElement(lib, keys, newValue) {
    var key = keys.shift();
    if (keys.length) {
        setElement(lib[key], keys, newValue)
    } else {
        lib[key] = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. Не до конца разъяснил задачу. Мне нужно получить именно ссылку к значению `lib` а не просто значение переменной, для того чтобы мог изменить его. А указанным способом, на сколько я понимаю, можно только увидеть значение переменной.

Comment: Тогда на последней итерации, когда keys.length == 1 (если сделали keys.shift(), то 0), вы просто присваиваете новое значение lib[key] = newValue. Все будет работать, так как объекты передаются по ссылке.

Comment: Обратите внимание, что если вы гдето будете хранить keys, то перед передачей в функцию getElement() сделайте его копию, так как keys.shift() меняет сам массив.